# Why can't kafka producer use the --bootstrap-server flag?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand the difference between the `--broker-list` and `--bootstrap-server` flags in Apache Kafka.

When using the kafka command line tools (as described in the [quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)):

- `kafka-console-producer.sh` requires `--broker-list` flag
- `kafka-console-consumer.sh` requires `--bootstrap-server` flag

Why can't the producer use a `bootstrap-server` but instead it's required to "manually" provide the list of brokers? Shouldn't the bootstrap server return metadata of all brokers that the producer could connect to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to `kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer` source code (program that is called by the bash script) you can see:

```scala
  def producerProps(config: ProducerConfig): Properties = {
    val props =
      if (config.options.has(config.producerConfigOpt))
        Utils.loadProps(config.options.valueOf(config.producerConfigOpt))
      else new Properties

    props ++= config.extraProducerProps

    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, config.brokerList) // <---- brokerList is passed as BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
```

Under the hood --broker-list is map to bootstrap.server property.
I think it is backward compatibility.

**Summarizing**: Both flags `--broker-list` and `--bootstrap-server` are mapped to same property

Answer (score 2):

It's just of a matter of different names for backward compatibility but they are actually the same. When you use `--broker-list` with the console producer you don't need to provide the full list of all brokers but at least one; so it's a bootstrap server list as it works for the console consumer.